# How to add the vertical parallel lines in the rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to add the vertical lines when I draw rectangle. The no of lines is dependent on the user and can be read from the text box.

I know the logic but somehow I am not able to get the answer.
I am calculating the width of the rectangle and then diving the width on the basis of no of vertical lines. 
Click the checkbox near rectangle and draw using mouse down events
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
      function PlotPitch()
  {
    var iPatches = document.getElementById('txtPatchCount').value;

    var iTop =  mySel.y;
    var iBottom = mySel.y + mySel.h;
    var iLeft =  mySel.x;
    var iX = iLeft;
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    context =  canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (var iPatch=1; iPatch<iPatches; ++iPatch) {
      iX = iLeft + iPatch*mySel.w/iPatches;
      context.moveTo(iX, iTop);
      context.lineTo(iX, iBottom);
    }
    context.lineWidth=0.25;
    context.stroke();
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5wcs/4/
If I am adding this the code is breaking and I am not able to draw anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do if you have 'strange' behaviour is to separate concerns, so in this case that could be by creating a function that you test separately, which draws the lines, then once it's tested ok, plug it in code by just calling the function. You should find quickly.
So begin by testing this :

```
function drawLines(Context, mySel, iPatches) {
   var iTop =  mySel.y;
   var iBottom = mySel.y + mySel.h;
   var iLeft =  mySel.x;
   var iX = iLeft;
   var colWidth = mySel.w/iPatches ;
   for (var iPatch=1; iPatch<iPatches; ++iPatch) {
      iX += colWidth;
      Context.moveTo(iX, iTop);
      Context.lineTo(iX, iBottom);
   }
   Context.lineWidth=0.25;
   Context.stroke();
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi @GameAlchemist I have already done this. I just need to ask where should I put it in the code to test this. Should I put it in init2 or callROi ?Where exactly so that it draws the line when I am drawing a rectangle. see my edit in the question.

Comment: I added a button to test this. that is working fine but when I move the rectangle it disappears and when I click the button again, it appears but the old one is also there at the place where I created it. SO in short I have multiple lines :(

Comment: look at this one : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/K5wcs/6/ i changed draw of box

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added a text box too in which I can ask the user for the no of text boxes.

Comment: Hi @GameAlchemist. I have a doubt. When you doubt click after drawing the rectangle you can see a square appears. When you select that square the lines appears in that too and disappears from the previous one.Instaed I want to have the lines only in the rectangle which I am drawing using the mouse events(by clicking the checkbox not by anything else) http://jsfiddle.net/K5wcs/8/